# Why do we get such a result for double boolean indexing in Numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I was surprised by the result of the last expression?

```
>>> from numpy import array, arange
>>> a = arange(12).reshape(3,4)
>>> b1 = array([False,True,True])             # first dim selection
>>> b2 = array([True,False,True,False])       # second dim selection
>>>
>>> a[b1,:]                                   # selecting rows
array([[ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
>>>
>>> a[b1]                                     # same thing
array([[ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
>>>
>>> a[:,b2]                                   # selecting columns
array([[ 0,  2],
       [ 4,  6],
       [ 8, 10]])
>>>
>>> a[b1,b2]                                  # a weird thing to do
array([ 4, 10])
```

I expected:

```
array([[ 4,  6],
       [ 8, 10]])
```

Do you have any explanation why it is the case?

Comment: `a[b1, :][:, b2]` would produce your expected output. And also check out the indexing doc in [NumPy User Guide](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) and in [NumPy Reference](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing).

Comment: yes, I tested it with: >>> a[:,b2][b1]
array([[ 4,  6],
       [ 8, 10]]) and >>> a[b1][:,b2]
array([[ 4,  6],
       [ 8, 10]])

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start with your array:

```
a = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
              [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
              [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

Your current indexing logic equates to the following:

```
a[[1, 2], [0, 2]]  # array([ 4, 10])
```

Sticking to 2 dimensions, NumPy interprets this as indexing dim1-indices `[1, 2]` and dim2-indices `[0, 2]`, or coordinates `(1, 0)` and `(2, 2)`. There's no broadcasting involved here.

To permit broadcasting with Boolean arrays, you can use [`numpy.ix_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html):

```
res = a[np.ix_(b1, b2)]

print(res)

array([[ 4,  6],
       [ 8, 10]])
```

The magic `ix_` performs is noted in the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html): "Boolean sequences will be interpreted as boolean masks for the corresponding dimension (equivalent to passing in `np.nonzero(boolean_sequence)`)."

```
print(np.ix_(b1, b2))

(array([[1],
        [2]], dtype=int64), array([[0, 2]], dtype=int64))
```

---

As a side note, you can use a more direct approach if you have integer indices:

```
b1 = np.array([1, 2])
b2 = np.array([0, 2])

a[b1[:, None], b2]
```

See also: [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51177843/numpy-indexing-broadcasting-with-boolean-arrays) on why this method does not work with Boolean arrays.